# How can i go to my App when i click on AppWidget

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

### How can i go to my App when i click on AppWidget

I saw no. of questions how to create widget in android home,but after craeting widget how to go to my app while clicking on that i didn't get from anyone of that.Please give me the guidelines to achieve this.

Thanks,

Comment: Add an on click listener to one of the views of your widged. In the onClick function create an intent with wich you start the main activity of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an `AppWidget` setting an **onClickListener won't work**. Instead you have to set an `onClickPendingIntent` on a specific view.

See the following code for the necessary steps (you should put this code into your `onUpdate()` method):

```
// Inflate the Widget layout
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                        R.layout.your_widget_layout);

// Create and set the Intent
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

// Add intent to a view (like a button)
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.your_button, pendingIntent);
```

***Please note:*** *The code only shows the relevant parts*

Answer (score 0):

As greenapps say :
Add a listener in your widged's view (e.g : click) 
Create an intent and put extra information (e.g witch item is clicked)
Then start your activity.

e.g

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        //...
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_layout, pendingIntent);
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: pls send me the sample snippet

Comment: yourView i.e widgetsview where it has created?